# How to see what metadata is changed when copying/moving, especially between Windows and Linux?

Tags: file-transfer, file-management, file-permissions

When I copy between Linux and Windows, either on local drives, external drives, or mounted network shares, I am sometimes surprised by how permissions and metadata get changed. Is there a way to see what got changed when I move/copy files and directories? Either using the built-in tools on Linux(Ubuntu/Xubuntu) or Windows, or with 3rd party software? I would prefer some kind of GUI file manager option so I can see that changes as I work on files in real time.